# youtube video embedding pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

How Can I embed youtube video using PyQt5? I tried doing the following,but it gave me an unresolved error:

> DirectShowService:doRender unresolved error code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtWebKit
from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
#from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets #import QWebEngineView,QWebEngineSettings

class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled,True)
        super(window,self).__init__()
        self.centralwid=QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.vlayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.webview=QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView()
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq4AbdNsFVw"))
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
        self.centralwid.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwid)
        self.show()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

You are importing some deprecated modules from PyQt5 ([`QtWebKit`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebKit.html), and [`QtWebKitWidgets`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.html#PyQt5-QtWebKitWidgets)). It seems you have the right paths commented out at the bottom of your imports.

If you resolve these issues and use the proper modules ([`QtWebEngineCore`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngineCore.html?highlight=webenginecore##PyQt5-QtWebEngineCore), [`QtWebEngineWidgets`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.html?highlight=qtwebenginewidgets##PyQt5-QtWebEngineWidgets)) it works on my system.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings

class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled,True)
        super(window,self).__init__()
        self.centralwid=QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.vlayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.webview=QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq4AbdNsFVw"))
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
        self.centralwid.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwid)
        self.show()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output I get looks like the following (which seems correct):

[image]

Comment: Actually I am using Windows(PyQt5,python 3.6) and I am having problems importing the EngineCore and EngineWidgets.No module Named QtWebEngineWidgets

Comment: What is your exact version of PyQt5?

Comment: exact version pyqt -> 5.6  and qt -> 5.6.2

Comment: Strange. Same versions here, just on OS X. Have you tried updating/reinstalling PyQt (not qt)?

Comment: can it be a windows issue?

Comment: @Grr the problem is not caused by the module, I have PyQt5 5.9 in linux and I have both modules, and in both they work correctly, the problem is DirectShow that maybe is an inadequate version

Comment: It seems this is a known issue in https://forum.qt.io/topic/86246/directshowplayerservice-dorender-unresolved-error-code-0x80040266/3 and https://forum.qt.io/topic/49572/directshowplayerservice-dorender-unresolved-error-code-80040218 . I have tried both in windows 10 but neither worked.

Comment: dont we have any alternative?