# Cannot play youtube live stream using PyQt

Tags: python, youtube, pyqt, embed, live

I am a new programmer. I am trying to play a youtube live stream in a python program using PyQt and the following code snippet derived from [youtube video embedding pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103685/youtube-video-embedding-pyqt).

```
self.centralwid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
self.webview = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ga3maNZ0x0w"))
self.vlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
self.centralwid.setLayout(self.vlayout)
```

This works perfectly with a normal youtube video, but when I try to play a live video, youtube gives the error "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available". I'm assuming this has to do with the format of live streams being different from normal videos (lives streams are in H.264), but I don't know how to resolve this. Please help!

Comment: In Linux with PyQt5 5.10 it works correctly: https://imgur.com/a/QQJ5rNo

Comment: Then could it be a problem with my pyqt or my system itself? When I follow youtube's help link that shows up in the python program it says that it is playing using the HTML5 video player and that H.264 is not supported in the browser. I'm using ubuntu and pyqt5 5.10, and the video plays fine in my web browser.

Comment: As far as I know Ubuntu does not support PyQt5 5.10 using the repositories, it would be interesting to describe what your OS is, what version of PyQt5, how you have installed PyQt5, etc., so we restrict the problem and it will be easier to distinguish where the problem is

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, PyQt5.10, and I believe I installed PyQt5 using pip3. Its in usr/lib/python 3/dist-packages. there have not been any other issues in my use of pyqt outside of this video issue.

Comment: update: it is a problem on my device, since the code works fine on my Macbook. H.264 is supported in my web browsers, but maybe not in my ubuntu system itself?

Comment: Check that backend you use, search your repos for the codecs and try to install them.

Comment: Can I add to this thread that I'm getting a similar issue on my Windows 10 using PyQt5 version 5.11.3? Can someone help me with this? Thanks.